# XML Column - using "with namespace" in an xmlColumn.value()

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to create a lesson to demonstrate namespaces. 
I have an XML column in my database that contains a FlighReservations root, with multiple FlightReservation elements.  Each FlightReservation is like a "row", and has various sub-elements which I want to display as columns.  I can get this to work without using namespaces, and now I want to do it with the namespace prefixes.

I have a reproducible sample here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=608c9bf89fe6ada200216fde855557c7

This is the T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc XML = 
 '<ns0:FlightReservations xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservations">
  <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation">
    <DepartureAirportCode>DFW</DepartureAirportCode>"
  </ns1:FlightReservation>
  <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation">
    <DepartureAirportCode>OKC</DepartureAirportCode>"
  </ns1:FlightReservation>
  </ns0:FlightReservations>
'
;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservations' as ns0, 
                    'http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation' as ns1, 
                    DEFAULT 'http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation'
                    )
select 
    t2.xmlDoc2.query('.') AS result  , 
    t2.xmlDoc2.value('(.//*[local-name()="DepartureAirportCode"])[1]','varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode1, 
    t2.xmlDoc2.value('(./ns1:FlightReservation/DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode2, 
    t2.xmlDoc2.value('(.//ns1:FlightReservation/DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode3, 
    t2.xmlDoc2.value('(.//DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode4, 
    t2.xmlDoc2.value('(.//ns1:DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode5 
    from @xmlDoc.nodes('//ns1:FlightReservation')  AS t2(xmlDoc2)
```

The from statement seems to be working as I am getting two rows of output with the result column set to this (with one or the other airport code):

```
<ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation">
  <DepartureAirportCode>DFW</DepartureAirportCode>"
</ns1:FlightReservation>
```

I'm able to test my xpaths separately using XpathTester.com: 
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/3a16744fb05e13264af788bb65210df5

The results shown in SQL 2019 are: 
[image]

The only one that works is where I use the local-name function, and the purpose of my demo is to use the ns1 prefix.  Maybe I have a typo, but I've been staring at it and trying things for a while, and cannot see it.  Should the "with namespace" setup also work in the .value clause?

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Comment: Please share desired output. What is the difference between DepartureAirportCode1 - DepartureAirportCode5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the T-SQL below.

Your XML has just two namespaces, not three. I adjusted the `.nodes()` method XPath expression. Columns that have NULL values have questionable *XPath* in the `.value()` method.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc XML = 
 '<ns0:FlightReservations xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservations">
  <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation">
    <DepartureAirportCode>DFW</DepartureAirportCode>"
  </ns1:FlightReservation>
  <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation">
    <DepartureAirportCode>OKC</DepartureAirportCode>"
  </ns1:FlightReservation>
  </ns0:FlightReservations>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservations' as ns0
    , 'http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation' as ns1)
select c.query('.') AS result  , 
    c.value('(.//*[local-name()="DepartureAirportCode"])[1]','varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode1, 
    c.value('(DepartureAirportCode/text())[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode2, 
    c.value('(.//ns1:FlightReservation/DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode3, 
    c.value('(.//DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode4, 
    c.value('(.//ns1:DepartureAirportCode)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS DepartureAirportCode5 
from @xmlDoc.nodes('/ns0:FlightReservations/ns1:FlightReservation')  AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|                                                           result                                                           | DepartureAirportCode1 | DepartureAirportCode2 | DepartureAirportCode3 | DepartureAirportCode4 | DepartureAirportCode5 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation"><DepartureAirportCode>DFW</DepartureAirportCode>" |                       |                       |                       |                       |                       |
|   </ns1:FlightReservation>                                                                                                 | DFW                   | DFW                   | NULL                  | DFW                   | NULL                  |
| <ns1:FlightReservation xmlns:ns1="http://SchemaLesson.FlightReservation"><DepartureAirportCode>OKC</DepartureAirportCode>" |                       |                       |                       |                       |                       |
|   </ns1:FlightReservation>                                                                                                 | OKC                   | OKC                   | NULL                  | OKC                   | NULL                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it was the extra "Default" namespace that was the issue.

Comment: I don't understand why (DepartureAirportCode/text())[1] works for DepartureAirportCode2.  This doesn't work in XPath Tester on what is in the "result" column. 
Why not (./ns1:FlightReservation/DepartureAirportCode)[1]?  I thought you had to specify one "." at the beginning when using the result of the "cross apply" or "nodes()"

Comment: @NealWalters, (1) XPath Tester, we don't know what engine is behind it. (2) no need in ".", no need in `ns1:FlightReservation`. The context is already below that element.